# API returning 500 error after changing one property from guid to string

Tags: c#, ajax, serialization, http-status-code-500

I have an API that returns a list of objects. The object has a field of type `IEnumerable<String>`. The field was originally populated with a list of Guid strings, set in Sitecore as a multilist:

```
characteristics.VertWilt = item.Fields.Get("vert wilt") != null ? item.Fields.Get("vert wilt").Split(',').Select(f =>f) : null;
```

However, I want to instead retrieve the values of the multilist items, not the Guid ids, because I don't want the Guids displaying on my page. So I changed the line to this:

```
characteristics.VertWilt = item.Fields.Get("vert wilt") != null ? item.Fields.Get("vert wilt").Split(',').Select(f => service.GetItem<IDropdownItem>(Guid.Parse(f)).Value) : null;
```

My code executes without error. This is the API code:

```
[HttpPost]
[HttpRoute("applyfilters")]
public HttpResponseMessage ApplyFilters([FromBody] FilterModel filters)
{
    VarietySelectorDataHelper helper = new VarietySelectorDataHelper(); 
    var data = helper.SearchVarieties(filters).Select(i => new VarietyModel(i)).OrderBy(v => v.SortOrder);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
}
```

`data` is populated as it should be, and the field characteristics.VertWilt looks like `option1, option2, option3` instead of `3F9F1AFC-4DD7-4445-83E2-CCBBB62BFF78,8A40AF0E-3F79-4060-BD9D-EE0A29CB1D52,B596A791-5917-45B6-BB2F-FE433FEE6039`

However, in the console I see a 500 error, and my data does not display on the page. I used Firebug to inspect the error.

```
"message": "An error has occurred.",
"exceptionMessage": "Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
)."
```

Why is it expecting a Guid? Where would this need to be changed?